# PHP file_get_contents outputs annoying characters?

Tags: file-get-contents

Im trying to file_get_contents from a website but it outputs strange characters like ��}�r�H��ߙ�y��M���n�'2I��"�^ÏjI-[D������T��8�w��|��-Y

```
<?
  echo file_get_contents("http://mp3yum.top");
?>
```

Is there any way to scrape some content from this site.

Comment: You must be trying to display non latin text on a non utf8 output. What is the file save format-is it utf8? If the file has HTML what is the content type charset encoding?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the CURL before calling to the external source.

```
$data = get_url('http://mp3yum.top');
echo($data);


function get_url($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
}
```

Output Screen:

[image]

Comment: Same output. Please provide working & tested solution only.